# slatejs and react-hot-loader

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

I try to implement `slatejs` package to my react app for creacting my custom editor,it works great,but hot-reloading stops working.
it stops when I do `import` into some component.I use webpack-dev-server+react-hot-loader

Firstly I supposed that the reason was my custom app settings ,but it didn't work for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app 
and for https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit too

As I can understand `slatejs` package uses browserify,maybe this is the reason,but it shouldn't have an effect cause it's just a package and webpack settings for react-hot-loader exclude `node_modules`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue,I don't know why but it helped.

```js
const { Editor, Raw }  = require('slate') // this import works with live-reload

import { Editor, Raw } from 'slate' // this import doesn't work with live-reload
```